# How to do step-by-step debugging for a Python package in PyCharm 5?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I have a Python package in PyCharm, they are executed in the format as below:

```
python -m mypackage
```

However, as the code is growing bigger, I need to track the data changes, so I need to do it step by step. I've tried to debug it as a script, but PyCharm prevented me by popping value errors:

> ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

I have to keep these relative imports since they are also written as Python packages.

Can anyone please teach me how to do it in PyCharm5?

Many thanks.